# Rotation of a figure around 2 different axis (say X and Y) (OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a figure based on the mouse position where a horizontal swipe will rotate it along the y axis and a vertical swipe will rotate it along the z axis. Now i followed [the tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html#rotate) on android development and was able to create a rotation about the z axis. I now want to combine it with rotation along the y axis. Here is a part of my code:-

```
Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix,0,mAngle,0,0,-1.0f);
//i added the following line
Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix2,0,mAngle2,0,-1.0f,0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch,0,mMVPMatrix,0,mRotationMatrix,0);
//and this line too
//i am rotating the already rotated figure on a different axis this time
Matrix.multiplyMM(temp,0,scratch,0,mRotationMatrix2,0);
mTriangle.draw(temp);
```

But when i run the above code, I am getting strange results. The code was working right before i added the 2 lines of code and the float matrix variable temp.

Answer (score 0):

You should multiply only once with MVP, and do no transform after, so at the end just before drawing.
Since VP is doing the transformation from space to camera to screen (so further transforms would be awkward, like having a camera looking the screen displaying another camera ;-) ).

Comment: And you (question author) likely should rotate second axis by the first rotation to get expected result.

Comment: This means that I'd have to combine the 2 rotations into a single rotation and then multiply it with the MVP to get the desired result. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: no, he suggest to put 2nd axis (0,-1,0) in a vector a2, and to rotate a2 by M1 (my multiplying matrix-vector).

Comment: [rewriten] combine or multiply apart, same thing (just take care of multiply orders). But his point was to put 2nd axis (0,-1,0) in a vector a2, and to rotate a2 by M1 (by multiplying matrix-vector).